# mocha not running all tests in test dir

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, chai

This is my folder structure

```
src/
   a.js
   b.js
   test/
     a.spec.js
     b.spec.js
```

and I've tried running

1. `~/.../src $ mocha`
2. `~/.../src $ mocha test`
3. `~/.../src $ mocha test/`
4. `~/.../src $ mocha ./test/`
5. `~/.../src $ mocha ./test/*.js`

but non worked... all I get is just one test file running and the rest are ignored.

The [docs](http://mochajs.org/#the-test-directory) say that (1) should do the job but well it doesn't.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This was my mistake. I had `it.only` in one of my files and I forgot it. Removing the `.only` was the answer. All the test files are running now.

Comment: not quite the same but similiar dump: in my case i created a new test file, but forgot to end the filename with `.test.ts`, which made mocha ignore it... Just for the case any other has this problem, too :D

Comment: You may want to use the [forbid only flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47019741/457268) in the future within your scripts, so that the usage of `it.only` is marked as an error.

Answer (score 7):

It's built like this so you can run your test suite on just a file or two if you're doing development on them.  If you want to run `mocha` throughout your project just specify `--recursive`

You can see some documentation [here](http://bpinto.github.io/posts/running-mocha-tests-on-subdirectories/).

Better yet, you can just specify it in your package.json for CD.  First do `npm install mocha --save-dev` and then put this in your `package.json` file then run `npm test`

```js
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/mocha --recursive",
  }
}
```

Comment: `--recursive` is for running test files in sub-folders but that is not my case. The output remains the same, only one file is used.

Answer (score -1):

Create a moch.opts file under test directory and add recursive option

--recursive

Run ~/.../src $ mocha command; it should work.