# How to make `it.only` environment-aware using mocha?

Tags: javascript, testing, build, mocha.js

Mocha supports `it.only` syntax to reduce the amount of tests to run. In our team, a developer might use `it.only` temporally within a code base.

Now it happened that such an `only` test was approved and deployed by accident. This led the build server to happily run only one test and to declare that build a success.

My question now becomes: Is there a way to tell mocha:

It should only allow `only` on a developer's machine? Can it be make environment aware so that either all tests always run on a build machine or an `only` test case would also declare the job a failure.

(I know that there are different ways to reduce the amount of tests run by mocha. E.g. within WebStorm one can run a subset of tests within a project without changing code. The scope of the question is to allow for the fact that a developer might use `it.only` and they shall be free to do so. I want to detect if such a change might sneak its way into the codebase though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your CI, you should run mocha with the [`forbid-only`](http://mochajs.org/#usage) flag.

```
--forbid-only    causes test marked with only to fail the suite
```

Depending on your setup it may look like:

```
mocha --require babel-register --recursive tests/unit --forbid-only
```

A developer still may chose to run the test suite without the flag.